# What is this sequence of polynomials?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, polynomials, summation

NovaDenizen says the polynomial sequence i wanted to know about has these two recurrence relations

(1) $p_n(x+1) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (x+1)^{n-i}p_i(x)$

(2) $p_{n+1}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{x} ip_n(i)$

==

i was trying to calculate the probability of something and i came upon them. i needed to know what this was equal to:

$$p_n(x)=\sum_{k_n=k_{n-1}}^{x}....\sum_{k_3=k_2}^{x} \sum_{k_2=k_1}^{x} \sum_{k_1=1}^{x}k_1k_2...k_n$$

$k \in (1,2,...,x)$.

if you make it continuous and over the reals instead of over the natural numbers then its not too hard to see what that equals.

$$p_n(x) \approx \int_{k_n=0}^{x}...\int_{k_3=k_2}^{x}\int_{k_2=k_1}^{x}k_1k_2k_ndk_1dk_2...dk_n =\dfrac{(x)^{2n}}{2^n n!}$$

i computed some of these and got

$$p_1(x) \approx \frac{x^2}{2}, p_2(x) \approx \frac{x^4}{8}, p_3(x) \approx \frac{x^6}{48}, p_4(x) \approx \frac{x^8}{384}, p_5(x) \approx \frac{x^{10}}{3840},...$$
so im assuming that's the formula.

from the summation formula its easy to see that $$p_1(x)=\sum_{k=1}^x k=\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$$

i spent some time to compute $$p_2(x)=\sum_{k_2=k_1}^x\sum_{k_1=1}^x k_1k_2=x^4/8+(5 x^3)/12+(3 x^2)/8+x/12=x (3 x+1) (x+1) (x+2)/24$$

these agree with the approximations from integrating, which im guessing gives the first terms of $p_n(x)$.

also i think its might be fair to say that $\dfrac{(x)^{2n}}{2^n n!} < p_n(x) < \dfrac{(x+1)^{2n}}{2^n n!}$ if you can use the integral approximation to get lower and upper estimates of $p_n(x)$.

but im wondering what this sequence of polynomials is. i think i can just use the first terms of them to calculate the probabilities i wanted to know well enough, but it wouldn't hurt to know if this sequence of polynomials has a name. thanks.

Comment: There's a recurrence relation.  $p_{n+1}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{x} ip_n(i)$, and $p_n(x+1) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (x+1)^{n-i}p_i(x)$

Comment: ooh cool. thanks a lot! i guess i noticed the first one when i was looking at the sum, but not the second one! i have _no_ idea how you got that, looks very strange to me.

Comment: That assumes $p_0(x) = 1$.  Maybe it would be better written $p_n(x + 1) = (x+1)^n + \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x+1)^{n-i}p_i(x)$.  $p_n(x+1)$ is $(x+1)^n$ plus the sum of all sequences of length $j$ and $\le x$ followed by $n-j$ instances of $x+1$.

Comment: thanks for explaining. i see what's going on now, well not fully see it like i would be confident enough to write that recursion  myself and defend it, but pretty close. when you take derivatives of each side from that recursion and evaluate at $x=0$ you can get $2n$ linear equations (each derivative you take gets you a new equation) in the $2n$ coefficients of $p_n$, and the first, say, $2$ coefficients to $p_n$ only depend on the first two of the others, so its not really that bad to calculate them, and those are the most useful ones to know.

Answer (score 1):

(some years later .. !)

Note that your polynomial can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 p_{\,n} (x) = \sum\limits_{k_{\,n}  = k_{\,n - 1} }^x { \cdots \sum\limits_{k_{\,2}  = k_{\,1} }^x {\sum\limits_{k_{\,1}  = 1}^x {k_{\,1} k_{\,2}  \cdots k_{\,n} } } }  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {}  \\
   {1\, \le \,k_{\,1} \, \le \,k_{\,2} \, \le \, \cdots \, \le \,k_{\,n} \, \le \,x}  \\
\end{array}} {\prod\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,n} {k_{\,j} } }  = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 x + 1 \\ 
 x - n \\ 
 \end{array} \right] \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
where the second line reproduces a known representation of the [unsigned Stirling Number of 1st kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) : that indicated in square brackets.

These numbers are normally defined for non-negative integers at the upper and lower term.

However, there is an interesting extension to the polynomials written as above, which goes through
the [Eulerian Numbers of 2nd kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number), here indicated within double angle brackets, and the binomials 
(expressed in the extended way through Gamma, or Falling Factorials), or equivalently through the [Stirling Numbers of 2nd kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), here in curly brackets.
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left[ \matrix{
  z \cr 
  z - n \cr}  \right]\quad \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le {\rm integer }n \hfill \cr 
  \;z \in \mathbb C \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\scriptstyle k \atop 
  \scriptstyle \left( {0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} \right)}  {\left\langle {\left\langle \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right\rangle } \right\rangle \left( \matrix{
  z + k \cr 
  2n \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left\{ \matrix{
  n + k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right\}\left( \matrix{
  n - z \cr 
  n + k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n + z \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n + k} \left\{ \matrix{
  n + k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right\}\left( \matrix{
  z + k - 1 \cr 
  n + k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n + z \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)}  \cr} 
$$
Refer for instance to the renowned "Concrete Mathematics" at the section on Eulerian Numbers.

Then, since the Stirling N. 1st kind obey to the fundamental recurrence
$$
\left[ \matrix{
  z + 1 \cr 
  z - n \cr}  \right] = z\left[ \matrix{
  z \cr 
  z - n \cr}  \right] + \left[ \matrix{
  z \cr 
  z - n - 1 \cr}  \right]
$$
you get the expression of your polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Let $q_n(a,b) = \sum_{k_1=a}^b \sum_{k_2 = k_1}^b \dots \sum_{k_n=k_{n-1}}^b k_1 k_2 \dots k_n$.

$p_n(x) = q_n(1,x)$

$q_1(a,b) = \dfrac{b(b+1)}{2} - \dfrac{a(a-1)}{2} $

$q_n(a,a) = a^n$

$q_{n+1}(a,b) = \sum_{i=a}^b iq_n(a,i) = \sum_{i=a}^b iq_n(i,b)$

$q_{n_1 + n_2 + 1}(a,b) = \sum_{i=a}^b q_{n_1}(a,i)iq_{n_2}(i,b)$

$q_2(a,b) = \sum_{i=a}^b iq_1(a,i) = \sum_{i=a}^b i\left(\dfrac{i(i+1)}{2} - \dfrac{a(a-1)}{2}\right) = \sum_{i=a}^b \dfrac{i^3}{2} + \dfrac{i^2}2 + i\dfrac{a(a-1)}{2}$

That last expression for $q_2$ is solvable as a power sum.

It seems to me that a solution for general $n$ wouldn't be any simpler than [Faulhaber's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaulhabersFormula.html).